# Remove all object in a list with double quotes in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list that contains object with double quotes like this: " " (note the space between the quotes). I try to remove all those objects from the list but when I escape the quotes it still doesn't work.

The object is imported from a txt file as one string containing all information and then turned to an array which I export to a list to later use RemoveAll from.

Text txt file looks like this when I import it:

```
"" "Myadress 6" "151 33 City" ""
```

The imported result is stored in a string "importedData" and then I do like this to work with it:

```
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\"" };
importedDataArray = importedData.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var importedDataList = markupDataArray.ToList();
importedDataList.RemoveAll(item => item == "\" \"");
```

I'm interested to keep those objects that actually containing something, not the one with " ".

Right now the list contains 6 object of which 4 of them looks like " ".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a relevant sample data for your list.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is `myList` a `List<string>`? If yes, why you don't say that?

Comment: May you please provide a [MCVE], because it's look like your `""` are show in the debug visualiser...

Comment: maybe you could also use `myList.RemoveAll(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item));`

Comment: Indeed, I wonder the same as @DragandDrop, are those quotes there, or are you looking in your debug visualiser that add them to indicate a string value? Give it a try without those (escaped) quotes and see what happens.

Comment: @FelixD. That did work! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add simply a where clause condition in your line like that :

```
var importedDataList = markupDataArray
     .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, still get the same result. All object with " " remains.

Comment: Show us datas example pls

Comment: @Tomas0910 i updated. If it doesn't work make sure you haven't specials chars in you string like `\n\r`